# Unity - how to lerp while a certain animation state is on?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, lerp

Ok, so I have an animationnthe speed of which is controlled by user's tapping m meaning I cant just lerp for a set time but have to have it depend on if this is true:

```
cameraAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("stillOpening")
```

By the end of this animation (no matter how long it took, fast or slow) I need this float in my material to have lerped to its final value:

```
skybox.SetFloat ("_Exponent1",Mathf.Lerp(skybox.GetFloat("_Exponent1"), topSkyBoxOpen, ratio));
```

Meaning it has to be equal to topSkyBoxOpen at the end of "stillOpening". I don't know how to coordinate the timing.

I have tried this in the Update():

```
void openSkyLerp()
    {
        float ratio = 0;
        float duration = 0.5f; // this is the one that will control how long it takes
        // value is in second 
        float multiplier = 1 / duration;

        while (cameraAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("stillOpening")) {
            ratio += Time.deltaTime * multiplier;
            skybox.SetFloat ("_Exponent1",Mathf.Lerp(skybox.GetFloat("_Exponent1"), topSkyBoxOpen, ratio));

        }
    }
```

But nothing happens at all - I read this might be because its trying to have it all lerp in 1 frame. Is this possible? How can I lerp WHILE an animation is playing regardless of its speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Meaning it has to be equal to topSkyBoxOpen at the end of
>   "stillOpening". I don't know how to coordinate the timing.

The problem is that you are not even waiting for a frame. So, even if your equation is correct, all those cannot happen smoothly in a single frame. You wait for a frame with `yield return null;` and that requires coroutine.

Answered a very similar but not the-same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649565/unity-coroutine-not-running-to-the-end/41651074#41651074) few hours ago.

If the `stillOpening` variable is the destination value, get the current `_Exponent1` value before going into the while loop. Have a counter variable that increments each frame while counter is less than `topSkyBoxOpen`. You can then use `Mathf.Lerp(currentVal, topSkyBoxOpen, counter / duration);` in the `SetFloat` function.

```
bool running = false;

void openSkyLerp()
{
    if (running)
    {
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    StartCoroutine(OpenSky(5));
}

IEnumerator OpenSky(float duration)
{
    float currentVal = skybox.GetFloat("_Exponent1");
    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < topSkyBoxOpen)
    {
        //Exit if not still opening
        if (!cameraAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("stillOpening"))
        {
            yield break;
        }
        counter = counter + Time.deltaTime;

        float val = Mathf.Lerp(currentVal, topSkyBoxOpen, counter / duration);

        skybox.SetFloat("_Exponent1", val);
        yield return null; //Wait for a frame
    }
    running = false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks that works for the animation at normal speed (btw where did you get the 5 for duration? Because thats the value that works) but when the user taps and speeds up the animation, the leaping only gets to around 6.28, not all the way

Comment: **where did you get the 5 for duration?** Nowhere. You can use any number. It simply means that it will gradually go from the current `_Exponent1` state to `topSkyBoxOpen` in *5* seconds. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: ** the leaping only gets to around 6.28, not all the way** This will go from the cucrrent value of `_Exponent1` to the value of `topSkyBoxOpen`. If `topSkyBoxOpen` is 6.28, it will stop at 6.28 so please check the value of your `topSkyBoxOpen` variable. If `topSkyBoxOpen` variable is a different value than it is stopping at, please remove `if (!cameraAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("stillOpening"))
        {
            yield break;
        }` from the code. Let me know if that solves your problem.